# Umbraco XSLT count media property of first value in multiple textstring

Tags: xslt, count, umbraco

I'm creating a macro that sources a property from the current member. The property uses the "multiple textstrings" datatype, and each textstring contains three values separated by commas a media ID, the version number and the date and time added.

e.g. 1475,1,28-Dec-12 01:26:45 (Media ID,version number,date and time added)

The first value is the media ID, on that mediatype I have a "protectedFile" true/false property. I want to count how many of the items in my list of multiple textstrings have that value set to "true"

I've tried the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="protectedFile">
        <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetCurrentMember()/assetDownloads/values/value">
                <xsl:variable name="contentSplit" select="umbraco.library:Split(current(), ',')" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$contentSplit/value">
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <xsl:if test="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)/protectedFile != '0'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(., 0)/protectedFile" />
                                </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<h3>Protected file: <xsl:value-of select="$protectedFile"/></h3>
```

But as it's a "for-each" the result is displayed as:
Protected file: 111

I need it to display as a count Protected file: 3

Can anybody assist me?

Cheers,
JV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do adding/substracting/etc in XSLT you need to use recursion.  That's done using xsl:call-template and having a secondary xsl:template that is like a function.  Something like this is a simple example:

```
<xsl:variable name="incrementVal" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:call-template name="addLoop">
    <xsl:with-param name="inc" select="$incrementVal" />
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="5" />
  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="addLoop">
  <xsl:param name="inc" />
  <xsl:param name="count" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$count = 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="$inc"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="addLoop">
        <xsl:with-param name="inc" select="$inc + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Put that in a test XSLT and use the XSLT test tool to see the result.